# How can I calculate how much weight a gyroscope can sustain (stabilize)?

Tags: forces

Hello I'm a highschooler conducting research about active gyroscopic stabilization and was just wondering if there is a theoretical way of calculating the weight a certain gyroscope can stabilize at different speeds. If you could give me some references or any literature about it, it would be greatly appreciated!